# Contributing to Gem - gem not updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to add a small bug fix to an open source gem. Here's what I've done:

```
cloned the repository to local
made changes and saved

changed gemfile of rails project to point to local version of gem 
> gem 'gem_name', path: "/Users/admin/gem_name"
> bundle install 
> bundle update gem_name
> rails s
```

The gem doesn't reflect any changes I've made (gem isn't updated). I had to change the `version.rb` file and then run `bundle update gem_name` to see changes. But to my understanding, this shouldn't be required to see changes?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you fork the gem in github? fix what you want and then point that for your github link... If you think your fix could be great for another users, why not a pull request? ;)

> gem 'gem_name', :git => 'https://github.com/my_user/gem.git'

Comment: I thought I could just clone the gem locally, make changes, then make a pull request to the original repo. But the gem isn't being updated after I make changes unless I change the `version.rb` file.